# Problem with import json to variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm new in React and I'm trying to import and save in variable a selected JSON data

```js
[...]

const languageToSet = "polish";
const lang = {
    promiseToSetLanguage: function(lang){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            import language from `./languages/${languageToSet}_lang.json`
            language = JSON.parse(language)
            if (language.welcome) {
                console.log('Works fine')
                resolve(true)
            } else{
                reject(false)
            }
        })
    }
}
lang.promiseToSetLanguage()

[...]
```

Console throw me a error:
"'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"
but i need to load a JSON file selected by user.
I used 'import' and 'require' method.

Thanks for your help, best regards.

Comment: try a dynamic import instead. The syntax is different. ```import(`./languages/${languageToSet}_lang.json`)``` usage would be something like `const lang = import('...')` and then `lang.default` would be the default export from a file

Answer (score 0):

I think that fetch might be the answer here..
Try to use

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const rawJsonFile = await fetch(`${file_from_user}`);
            const jsonFile = await rawJsonFile.json();
            if (jsonFile.welcome) {
                console.log('Works fine')
                resolve(true)
            } else{
                reject(false)
            }
        })
```

If it still wont work, you can always use xhr

Comment: you'd need to have the files hosted statically on the website for this to work I believe.

Comment: @JohnRuddell From his import statement in the original code, it looks like the user select a language from a predefined languages files located on the website..

Comment: its a local file import in javascript, thats quite different from a fetch request to a statically hosted file

Comment: In that case, require should have done the trick no? He said he tried it and it didn't worked

Comment: If you look at the error message, `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` this is what you would see if you write `import xxxx from 'xxxx'` inside a function vs at the top level of the file. I have used dynamic imports to handle this exact use case, you could update your answer to include that and I'd give you a +1 :)